# CSS & PHP; Add URL inside

Tags: php, css

```
<?php $picNumberSlide = "<div id='slidenumber'></div>" ;?>
```

**Num Print**

`<div id="slidenumber"></div>`  -> (Picture slide number)

**Link**

```
<a href="share?picNum=<?php echo $picNumberSlide;?>">
```

Not work.

`<div id='slidenumber'></div>` slide number of the screen writes.
I intended to write inside the URL's

How i can do? Thank you!
*(i sorry for Eng)*

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php $picNumberSlide = "<div id='slidenumber'></div>" ;?>
```

The above defines the $picNumberSlide variable as a div.

```
<a href="share?picNum=<?php echo $picNumberSlide;">
```

Here you are placing a div inside the href of an anchor, that will never work.

You need to assign the $picNumberSlide variable only the number you wish to use.

Then using

```
<a href="share?picNum=<?php echo $picNumberSlide; ?>">
```

will work.

**$picNumberSlide should only = a number**

Comment: You forgot to close the php tag.

Comment: True. Edited. I was just copy/pasting.

Comment: Thank you! Results (written in screen); `<a href="share?picNum=<div id='slidenumber'></div>"` The required number but the text is written.

Answer (score 0):

Change `<a href="share?picNum=<?php echo $picNumberSlide;">`

To `<a href="share?picNum=<?php echo $picNumberSlide;?>">`

(You were missing the closing tag for php)